# Android WebView is not pausing

Tags: javascript, android, webview, onpause

I have an app which shows some content in WebView. The content is loaded from the external storage. Web Socket is connecetd to this webview. My problem is that sometimes the webview's background processes are not stoped when I get out of the app (by pressing home or back button). I'm calling webView.onPause() and onResume() methods in the activity's onPause and onResume bu this doesn't help. If I press the home button sometimes I can see some javascript outputs from he web console. 
The webview is playing videos which are played through the web socket. Sometimes when my app is not on top I can still hear the sound of the video.

What could be the problem? 
It is really strange and annoying... Please let me know if you need more information provided. Thanks!